# Additional DNS server questions

Tags: internal-dns

I spun up an additional DC today for our domain and made it a DNS server as well via the wizard during the DC promotion. Prior to this, we only had a single DC which was also the only DNS server.

After Joining the new server to the domain and promoting it, I remoted onto the old DC and opened up DNS. I went to the zone properties and under the “name servers” tab I added the FQDN of the new server. Next on the “zone transfers” tab I chose the option to allow zone transfers to “only the servers listed under the name servers tab”.

Next, I logged onto the new DC and opened up DNS. I can see the zone referencing my domain but when I go into the properties, the “zone transfers” tab is not set to allow any. Not sure if it should be this way or not? I wanted the additional DNS for redundancy in case the old one goes down. Not sure how I need to configure the “Zone Transfers” tab on the new server or If I need to add a new zone. our only zone is a primary AD integrated zone. I thought AD integrated DNS zones don't rely on zone transfers but wanted to confirm that.

Next, on the old server when I open DHCP and check my scope options, under “006 Name Server” it still only lists the original DNS server. Do I need to manually add the new IP?

Lastly, the servers NIC DNS properties for DNS1 and DNS2. The primary DNS IP should point to each other and the secondary IP should be the loopback (127.0.0.1)?

Here is a screenshot of DNS from the newly created DC/DNS server

https://i.stack.imgur.com/lKG6u.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Configure the DNS zone(s) as AD integrated. That way the zone will replicate via AD rather than using a Primary/Secondary mechanism.
2. Yes you need to add the new DNS server to your DHCP Scope\Server options.
3. Each DC should point to it's partner for primary DNS, itself for secondary DNS, and 127.0.0.1 for tertiary DNS.

Comment: Thanks for confirming!

Comment: Glad to help...